# Dell xps 13 ubuntu 16.04, black screen after closed lid, can't turn off

Tags: 16.04, xps

It's a Dell xps 13 l322x from 2013. I'm running ubuntu 16.04 LTS. It happened the second time now. I closed the lid yesterday night with power cord attached. Today when I opened it the screen is black. The fan is running but I  don't know if it's since yesterday or it woke up to this state from sleep. Holding down the power button for a long time does not turn off (or on)  the computer. The keyboard back light is off. The indicator light below the TouchPad is on.  I've tried to blindly launch a shell and run shutdown commands of all sorts. But I see no reaction.

Last time I had to wait for the battery to drain, so that is what I'm doing now.

It like the computer is brain dead. It's obviously on and speeding up the fans now and then, and the indicator is on. But the screen is black and keyboard backlight is off and it is seemingly unresponsive to input.

Does any one have an idea about what kind of state the computer is in, and how to get out of it other than draining the battery?

Comment: It also happened to me, about 3 times, in 3 years. The only way around it was to open it and unplug the battery (or let it drain). Only afterwards start again. I also wonder if there is a way to make sure that never happens again.

Comment: Aha, is it a similar computer?

Comment: Yes, XPS 13 L322X. I'm currently using Fedora 24. I don't think this is a Ubuntu specific issue. Must be something between kernel and hardware. Just don't know exactly where neither what causes it.